# list view change item randomly

Tags: java, android, listview, conflict

I have a listview that when I change the value of one item (count) with click on plus button, Everything is fine as long as the user do scroll down and show more items 
And we see that on each page of the scroll has changed a value of item!!!
idont kNow why everything seems fine!!

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

    private  String[] from;
    ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> BuyList ;
    private  int[] to;
    private Context context;
    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data ;
    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> selecteddata;
    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> fdata ;
    private  ImageView pay,more;
    private  EditText search;
    private  String user_mobile;
    private  TextView buy_toolbar_count;
    private Holder holder;
   // private HashMap<String, Object> hm;

    public MyAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data,
                      ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> selecteddata , String[] from, int[] to, ArrayList Bylist,
                      ImageView pay, ImageView more, String user_mobile, TextView buy_count_toolbar, EditText search) {
        this.data = data;
        this.selecteddata = selecteddata;
        this.fdata = new ArrayList<>(selecteddata);

        this.context = context;
        this.from  = from;
        this.to  = to;
        this.BuyList = Bylist;
        this.pay = pay;
        this.more = more;
        this.search = search;
        this.user_mobile = user_mobile;
        this.buy_toolbar_count = buy_count_toolbar;

    }


    public  void filter(String s, ImageView img) {
        HashMap<String, Object> wp = new HashMap<>();

        if (!s.equals("")) {

            fdata.clear();
            for (int i = 0 ;i<data.size();i++) {
                wp = data.get(i);
                // Log.i("mosi",wp.get("name").toString() + " wp  ");

                if (wp.get("name").toString().toLowerCase().contains(s)) {


                    fdata.add(wp);




                }

            }

        }
        else {
            fdata = new ArrayList<>(selecteddata);

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class Holder
    {

        ImageView g_img;
        ImageView plus;
        ImageView mines;
        TextView g_name;
        TextView g_price;
        TextView g_off;
        TextView count;
        TextView f_range;
        TextView sum;
        TextView temp2;
    }
   @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fdata.size();
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> getItem(int i) {
        return fdata.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        Typeface font_titr = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/titr.TTF");
        final HashMap<String, Object> hm = fdata.get(position);


        if (convertView == null ) {
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                    inflate(R.layout.my_row_layout2, parent, false);

            holder.g_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_img);
            holder.g_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_name);
            holder.g_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_price);
            holder.g_off = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_off);
            holder.count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_count);
            holder.f_range = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_kilo);
            holder.plus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus_id_btn);
            holder.mines = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mines_id_btn);
            holder.sum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_sum_id);
            holder.temp2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

            //Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
 // Log.i("mosi",convertView.getTag() + "  tagfffff  " + hm.get("convertview"));



 hm.put("convertview", "1");



        }
        else
        {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

//            Log.i("mosi",convertView.getTag() + "  tag  " + hm.get("convertview"));
        }




        final View tempview = convertView;



// set font++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


        holder.g_price.setTypeface(font_titr, Typeface.NORMAL);
        holder.g_name.setTypeface(font_titr, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.g_off.setTypeface(font_titr, Typeface.NORMAL);
        holder.count.setTypeface(font_titr, Typeface.NORMAL);
        holder.sum.setTypeface(font_titr, Typeface.NORMAL);
        holder.temp2.setTypeface(font_titr, Typeface.NORMAL);


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        // Set pre count and sum

        holder.sum.setText(" میلغ کل : " + hm.get("sum").toString() + " تومان ");
        holder.count.setText(hm.get("count").toString());




        final String oldprice = hm.get("price").toString();




        holder.g_off.setText(hm.get("off").toString());
        holder.g_name.setText(hm.get("disc").toString());
        holder.f_range.setText(hm.get("f_range").toString());
        final float f=
                (Float.valueOf(oldprice)*
                        Float.valueOf(holder.g_off.getText().toString()))/100;

        // holder.g_price.setText(" قیمت :  "+ DtoS((Float.valueOf(oldprice.toString()))-f)+" تومان ");
        holder.g_price.setText(" قیمت :  "+  oldprice +" تومان ");



        File imageFile = new  File(hm.get("image").toString());
        if(imageFile.exists()){
            holder.g_img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
        else
            holder.g_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.coming_soon);





        holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                change_count(holder, hm, "p", tempview, ChangeType.DtoS((Float.valueOf(oldprice.toString())) - f), position);

            }

        });
        holder.mines.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                change_count(holder, hm, "m", tempview , ChangeType.DtoS((Float.valueOf(oldprice.toString()))-f), position);









            }
        });


// Button Pay && More

        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (BuyList.size() > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Payment_act.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("data", BuyList);
                    intent.putExtra("all_data", data);

                    intent.putExtra("mobile", user_mobile);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
//
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "سبد خرید شما خالی است", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Choose_act.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("blist", BuyList);
                intent.putExtra("data", data);
                intent.putExtra("mobile", user_mobile);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                //   ((Activity)context).finish();
            }
        });



// Search -------------------------------------------------------------------

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                //  Log.i("mosi", s+"  ---  s ***");
                //  filter(s.toString(), holder.g_img);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });





        return convertView;

    }


// template





    // Onclick for mines and plus Button
    //@Override
    public void change_count(final  Holder holder1, HashMap<String, Object> hm_addtolist, String tag, View c_view, String oldprice, int position) {

       // Log.i("mosi", position+"  position on list ");
        String is_pack = hm_addtolist.get("is_pack").toString();
        ChangeType ch = new ChangeType();
        double temp1 = 0;
        double p_with_off = 0;

        holder = (Holder) c_view.getTag();

        String off = hm_addtolist.get("off").toString();

        String num_sum = "0";



        if (ch.stringToDouble(off)>0)
        {
            p_with_off = ch.stringToDouble(hm_addtolist.get("price_with_off").toString());
        }
        else
            p_with_off = ch.stringToDouble(oldprice.toString());




        holder.count= (TextView) c_view.findViewById(R.id.f_count);
        holder.sum = (TextView) c_view.findViewById(R.id.count_sum_id);




        if (!holder.count.getText().toString().equals("") && holder.count!= null)
            temp1 = ch.stringToDouble(holder.count.getText().toString());
        //my_alert("", temp1+"");

        if (tag.equals("p")) {
            if (is_pack.equals("1"))
                temp1 = temp1 + 1;
            else
                temp1 = temp1 + 0.5;

            //  Log.i("mosi", " ::: set 2 !!!!");
            holder.count.setText(DtoS(temp1));

            num_sum = String.format("%d", (long)(temp1 * p_with_off));


            holder.sum.setText(" میلغ کل : " + num_sum + " تومان ");

        } else if (tag.equals("m")) {


            if (is_pack.equals("1")) {
                if (temp1 > 1) {
                    temp1 = (temp1 - 1);
                    holder.count.setText(DtoS(temp1));

                    num_sum = String.format("%d", (long) (temp1 * p_with_off));
                    holder.sum.setText(" میلغ کل : " + num_sum + " تومان ");

                } else {
                    holder.count.setText("0");
                    holder.sum.setText("مبلغ کل : 0 تومان");
                    num_sum = "0";
                    BuyList.remove(hm_addtolist);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    buy_toolbar_count.setText(String.valueOf(BuyList.size()));
                }

            }
            else {
                if (temp1 > 0.5) {
                    temp1 = (temp1 - 0.5);
                    holder.count.setText(DtoS(temp1));

                    num_sum = String.format("%d", (long) (temp1 * p_with_off));
                    holder.sum.setText(" میلغ کل : " + num_sum + " تومان ");

                } else {
                    holder.count.setText("0");
                    holder.sum.setText("مبلغ کل : 0 تومان");
                    num_sum = "0";
                    hm_addtolist.put("count","0");
                    hm_addtolist.put("sum","0");
                    BuyList.remove(hm_addtolist);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    buy_toolbar_count.setText(String.valueOf(BuyList.size()));
                }
            }
        }



        //}

        if (!num_sum.equals("0")) {
            hm_addtolist.put("sum", num_sum);
            hm_addtolist.put("count", holder.count.getText().toString());
            boolean check = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < BuyList.size(); i++) {
                if (BuyList.get(i).get("name").toString().equals(hm_addtolist.get("name").toString())) {
                    check = true;
                    HashMap<String, Object> temp_updatelist = BuyList.get(i);
                    temp_updatelist.put("sum", num_sum);
                    temp_updatelist.put("count", holder.count.getText().toString());
                    //  BuyList.add(temp_updatelist);
         //           Log.i("mosi",  "add count "+i+"");
                    // Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            if (!check) {
  //              Log.i("mosi",  "add count to ::  "+hm_addtolist.get("name")+"");
                BuyList.add(hm_addtolist);
                buy_toolbar_count.setText(String.valueOf(BuyList.size()));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }


        notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Log.i("mosi", BuyList.toString());

        //   clearbug( c_view);
    }






}
```

make list on activity

I have a listview that when I change the value of one item (count) with click on plus button, Everything is fine as long as the user do scroll down and show more items 
And we see that on each page of the scroll has changed a value of item!!!
idont kNow why everything seems fine!!

```
 private void setlist() {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> selected_data = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < all_data.size(); i++) {
            if (all_data.get(i).get("type").toString().equals(mtag)) {
                HashMap<String, Object> t = all_data.get(i);

                selected_data.add(t);
            }
        }
        //Log.i("mosi",selected_data.toString());
        EditText search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search_id);
        ImageView pay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_pay_firstpage);
        ImageView more = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_more_firstpage);


        String[] from = {"image", "name", "price", "off"};
        int[] to = {R.id.f_img, R.id.f_name, R.id.f_price, R.id.f_off};
        final MyAdapter adb = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext(), all_data, selected_data, from, to, BuyList, pay, more, user_mobile, buyCount_toolbar, search);



    lv.setAdapter(adb);

}
```

I have a listview that when I change the value of one item (count) with click on plus button, Everything is fine as long as the user do scroll down and show more items 
And we see that on each page of the scroll has changed a value of item!!!
idont kNow why everything seems fine!!

its my activity layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background_theme">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_message"
        layout="@layout/message"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mytoolbar"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/searchbox_id"
        layout="@layout/searchbox"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_message"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchbox_id"

    android:id="@+id/FirstPage_id">



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rv_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainLayoutActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/listDivader"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/my_listview"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_back"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_pay_firstpage"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"

            android:src="@drawable/btn_pay" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_more_firstpage"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"

            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_more" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_fragment"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout="@layout/drawer_fragment_layout"
    tools:layout="@layout/drawer_fragment_layout"
    android:name="com.com.seyedi89gmail.sm.zanco.Drawer_fragment">

</fragment>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you tell me where you are Incrementing count

Comment: on changecount function

Comment: Then you need to manage count by position

Comment: i do exactly that but i don know why some other items also changedd

Comment: I check the listview items tag, and some of them have same tag :OOO

Comment: I check the listview items tag, and some of them have same tag :OOO , Items tag repeated every 6 items!

Comment: Thanks every body, after some hard hours i found and solve the problem on adapter, edited adapter posted for who need :********************

Answer (score 0):

Remove notifyDataSetChanged from if-else conditions, May this will work

```
 public  void filter(String s, ImageView img) {
        HashMap<String, Object> wp = new HashMap<>();

       if (!s.equals("")) {

            fdata.clear();
            for (int i = 0 ;i<data.size();i++) {
                wp = data.get(i);


                if (wp.get("name").toString().toLowerCase().contains(s)) {



                    fdata.add(wp);


                    //notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }

        }
        else {
           fdata = new ArrayList<>(selecteddata);
           //notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  NestedScrollview outside the listview and stop the scrolling of listview by using this: smoothScrollBy(0, 0);

Comment: can you more explain please

Comment: like this :

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

Comment: its just showing one item is list view and not scroling :|

Comment: it show your listview scrolling functionality  transfer to nestedscrollview . don't forget to stop the scrolling of listview.

Comment: i set listview.smoothScrollBy(0, 0); but still not working

Comment: remove listview and use recyclerview

Comment: recyclerview is same, i change to recyclerview and not solved :/

Comment: add this in your recyclerview : recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

Comment: Thanks every body, after some hard hours i found and solve the problem on adapter, edited adapter posted for who need :********************